# For all the unique 'words" of a column, the find unique cells from another column , then average corresponding values of another column in python

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have A FILE.CSV with the following data

| colA | colB | colD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FCPP | 2019 | 5 |
| FCPP | 2020 | 20 |
| FCPP | 2020 | 10 |
| PSGS | 2020 | 20 |
| PSGS | 2019 | 30 |
| PSGS | 2019 | 20 |

I want to get the unique name from colA and then find out the corresponding unique year from the colB, and then average the value of colD. My output should look like following

| colA | colB | colD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FCPP | 2019 | 5 |
| FCPP | 2020 | 15 |
| PSGS | 2019 | 25 |
| PSGS | 2020 | 20 |

I know how find unique values in pandas using  df.unique() and I can use

```
df.groupby(['colA'])['colD'].mean()
```

But not sure how to fit colB in the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby(['colA','colB'],as_index=False).mean()
Out[114]: 
   colA  colB  colD
0  FCPP  2019     5
1  FCPP  2020    15
2  PSGS  2019    25
3  PSGS  2020    20
```